# C# Array of textBox in TextBox to build Sudoku Board

Tags: c#, winforms, solid-principles

I want to create a sudoku table, I have to add on each text box that will contain a unique number, 5 other text boxes on each other side of the initial text box to add a number as a draft for the user. I want to know if there is another solution to do it with Windows Form?
Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private TextBox textBox1;
        private TextBox textBox2;
        private TextBox textBox3;
        private TextBox textBox4;
        private TextBox textBox5;
        private TextBox textBox6;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                    this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                    this.textBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                    this.textBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                    this.textBox5 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                    this.textBox6 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                    this.SuspendLayout();
                    // 
                    // textBox1
                    // 
                    this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20 + (i * 39), 85 + (j * 39));
                    this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
                    this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
                    this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(106, 94);
                    this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
                    this.textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;

                    this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
                    for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
                        for (int b = 0; b < 5; b++)
                        {
                            // 
                            // textBox2
                            // 
                            this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 26);
                            this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
                            this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(21, 20);
                            this.textBox2.TabIndex = 1;
                            // 
                            // textBox3
                            // 
                            this.textBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 64);
                            this.textBox3.Name = "textBox3";
                            this.textBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(21, 20);
                            this.textBox3.TabIndex = 2;
                            // 
                            // textBox4
                            // 
                            this.textBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(114, 100);
                            this.textBox4.Name = "textBox4";
                            this.textBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(21, 20);
                            this.textBox4.TabIndex = 3;
                            // 
                            // textBox5
                            // 
                            this.textBox5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 100);
                            this.textBox5.Name = "textBox5";
                            this.textBox5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(21, 20);
                            this.textBox5.TabIndex = 4;
                            // 
                            // textBox6
                            // 
                            this.textBox6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(114, 26);
                            this.textBox6.Name = "textBox6";
                            this.textBox6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(21, 20);
                            this.textBox6.TabIndex = 5;
                        }
                            // 
                            // Form1
                            // 
                            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
                            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
                            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox6);
                            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox5);
                            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox4);
                            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox3);
                            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
                            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
                            this.Name = "Form1";
                            this.Text = "Form1";
                        }
                }
        }
    }
```

I have tried to create a Form that contains an array of textBoxes of 81 total boxes, and I would like to add 5 more textBoxes in each corner of the 81 TextBoxes, however these TextBoxes must take a Number between 1 and 9
https://cdn.britannica.com/42/97142-131-E3E24AA5/sudoku-puzzle-games.jpg

Thank you

Comment: I have to ask… is there some reason you want to use 81 different `TextBoxes`? Would not a simple 9x9 “grid” be easier to manage?

Comment: I'm not clear on what the question is.

Comment: I'll explain, I have to create a sudoku grid 9 lines and 9 columns, and on each of the boxes and on each corner of these boxes I must have text areas like this image https://github.com/wflageol-uqtr/inf1035/raw/master/resources/sudoku-coins.png

Comment: I think I have a solution I have to use panels to parameter the textbox